# Kozilek vs Stonecloaker

Tags: magic-the-gathering

So what i wanted to ask is this... [Kozilek, Butcher of Truth](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Kozilek%2C%20Butcher%20of%20Truth) goes to graveyard and I have [Stonecloaker](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Stonecloaker) in hand!
My queston is can I exile Kozilek with my Stonecloaker before Kozileks ability resolves ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can. Because when Kozilek goes to the graveyard, the "shuffle it into library" goes on the stack. Before that resolves, you can exile it from the graveyard with Stonecloaker.

The "shuffle it into library" is a so called triggered ability, therefore it goes on the stack and you can put your (instant or flash) spells on the stack before resolving that ability.

Comment: But wouldn't the stack resolve anyway? So you exile Kozilek, but then afterwards the "shuffle into library" still resolves since it is on the stack? Then all you have done is made sure Kozilek doesn't get placed in your library, but that is all? Wouldn't it be alot easyer to use the return a creature you control before damage is dealt and Kozilek dies? You'll still have him in your hand then.

Comment: @Lyrion, Yes, the "shuffle your graveyard into your library" ability will still resolve. I'm not sure what you mean by your "wouldn't it be a lot easier" comment. I assume the OP is trying to exile his opponent's Kozilek, not his own, in which case Kozilek isn't a valid choice for the "return a creature you control" ability.

Comment: @Kevin That is true did not think about that.

Comment: yea I was thinking about opponents Kozilek, we have a EDH group where Kozileks shuffle ability gives our friend infinite recursion, so I was wondering on how to remove him :) Thank you guy